# Derivation Nadaraya-Watson Estimator

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Can someone give me a hint how, in the introduction to the Nadaraya-Watson Estimator, the property

\begin{align}
\int y K(y-y_i)\, \mathrm{d}y = y_i,
\end{align}
where $K$ is a kernel function, can be proved as in [this publication](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~peterf/MATH38011/NPR%20N-W%20Estimator.pdf)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you substitute $y-y_i$  by $\psi$ you get

$$
\int (\psi + y_i) K(\psi)\mathrm{d}\psi \\
= \int  \psi  K(\psi)\mathrm{d}\psi + y_i \int K(\psi)\mathrm{d}\psi
$$

Now it is easy to see. The first integral is $E[\psi]$ with $K(\psi)$ being the density function. This is assumed to be $0$.  The second integral must be $1$ since you now integrate over the whole density. What you are left with is simply $y_i$.